# "Class" object can't be created

Tags: java, android

I am making a Class object in order to start a new activity. But the problem is when I type

```
Class ourclass = new Class.__
```

It doesn't recognise the Class and I can't use the methods of the super class "Class". It says class is a raw type. What type should I assign it to, because I want to use "forName()" method in which I want to pass a class name.
Here is the code

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try
    {
        Class ourclass =Class.__ // The suggestions for static functions doesn't popup, and I get errors
        //Intent myintent = new Intent();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Regards.

Comment: You need to let the JVM create a Class for you as the object is a proxy for internal data structures for the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What type should I assign it to, because I want to use "forName()" method in which I want to pass a class name.

[`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) is a *static* method - you don't call it on an instance:

```
Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("foo.bar.Baz");
```

(Whether this is actually appropriate or not when starting an activity is a different matter, but this answer just addresses the `Class.forName` part...)

Comment: Ok so I passed Class.forName() directly as an argument to a function as you suggested but still it gives me the same error, Type not Resolved..

Comment: That doesn't sound like the same error as "class is a raw type". Please edit your question with the *exact* code and the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Class.forName`, just call `Class.forName(name)`, don't use a (nonexistent) constructor.  `forName` is a static method, so you don't need a `Class` to invoke it on.